# Where is the alternate exit on Water's Edge Way?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

In the Water's Edge Way level, I know there is an alternate exit that allows me to get to the one level in that area that I haven't finished. Problem is, I have played the level a few times now and haven't been able to find the alternate exit!

How do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter the level, make way to the waterfall bridge. When you get there, hold <kbd>Up</kbd> to enter the waterfall.

You'll find the other Comet Sticker piece in there and a path to Whammino Mountain (World 1-5).